# Ng2-charts crosshair plugin not working in Angular

Tags: angular, graph, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am trying to use the crosshair plugin of ng2-charts in Angular 5 application. I need to use crosshair to interpolate points. This is a demo I found in the documentation: https://chartjs-plugin-crosshair.netlify.app/samples/.
In the docs, it says the plugin will allow us to use *tooltip mode* as "**interpolate**". But it is not working.

I installed the plugin via NPM and imported it in my application. Then I added the plugin option. But the plugin is not appearing. The app says module "chartjs-plugin-crosshair" is missing. Couldn't find any solution after googling for a day. I am giving the stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-crosshair-plugin

```
public lineChartOptions = {
    
    responsive: true,

    tooltips:{
      enabled: true,
      intersect: false,
      mode: "x" //"interpolate"
    },

    plugins:{

       crosshair:{
    
          line:{
            color:'#000',
            width: 3
          }
       }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the dependency for `chart.js` and the crosshair was displayed.

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-crosshair-plugin-cvxt77)

Here is another [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sex9k8) which uses the charts-crosshair-plugin.

Comment: Yes, now the crosshair is coming. The plugin docs said that Chart.js 2.6.0 or later is required. Guess the doc is outdated.

Comment: I have added the interpolation mode also. The problem was the 'type' option. It needs to be set as 'scatter' rather than 'line'. 3rd graph in this link demonstrates - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-crosshair-tryout